# Is it possible to deep link to a specific page or location in the Facebook mobile app on iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook

Is it possible to include a link inside my mobile app that opens the native Facebook app to a specific page, event, post, or other location?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
fb://profile – Open Facebook app to the user’s profile
fb://friends – Open Facebook app to the friends list
fb://notifications – Open Facebook app to the notifications list (NOTE: there appears to be a bug with this URL. The Notifications page opens. However, it’s not possible to navigate to anywhere else in the Facebook app)
fb://feed – Open Facebook app to the News Feed
fb://events – Open Facebook app to the Events page
fb://requests – Open Facebook app to the Requests list
fb://notes- Open Facebook app to the Notes page
fb://albums – - Open Facebook app to Photo Albums list
```

E.g.

```
 fb://post/(postId)
```

Then call like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://<insert function here>"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Source with LOTS more examples: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on iOS 6 - fb://*** opens the Facebook App, but not at the specified content.

Comment: Yep, iOS6 and facebook integration broke most of the facebook url schemes.

Comment: How about for a business page? It would normally be www.facebook.com/mybusiness.