# Open the Facebook App to a specific Page

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

This line of code

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (NSUrl.FromString ("fb://page/319284411498623"));
```

or

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (NSUrl.FromString ("fb://profile/319284411498623"));
```

does not seem to work. I'm trying to open the WordRoom facebook page (no advertising intended, just disclosing all information needed). It opens the Facebook app, but only the main feed. The Facebook app was downloaded today and iOS 6.1.2 running.

The ID is fetched from this page: http://graph.facebook.com/wordroom

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Johan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of :
[Is it possible to deep link to a specific page or location in the Facebook mobile app on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149143/is-it-possible-to-deep-link-to-a-specific-page-or-location-in-the-facebook-mobil)

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://<insert function here>"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

You should also test if fb app is installed (by testing if iOS can open URL):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url];
```

Comment: If you read the comments on the answer Hugh linked to, it notes that iOS6 broke FB deep linking.

Comment: So in practice there is no way to do this if you are targeting iOS6. Why would they break the schema?