# Facebook Deep Link

Tags: facebook

I have a website which will share a facebook video post on facebook page to user's facebook account. The facebook video link is something like that https://www.facebook.com/{page-id}/video/{video-id}.

After I posted this link to user's facebook account, I get back the post id like xxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxx. is it possible to open this post from native facebook app on mobile? I tried to make a link like this:

```
<a href="fb://profile/xxxxxxx_xxxxxx">Open your post</a>
```

The facebook app does open but it just show me the news feed page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11149317/1427878, http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

Comment: thanks! I tried the fb://post/{id} as well. But the result is the same.

Comment: Yeah, as it says in the wiki: _“It only works if the Facebook app has previously loaded the particular post, otherwise it draws a blank”_ – so it seems that is not really an option for general use.