# What is the Android URL Schema for Facebook Profiles

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I want to use Linking in React Native to open Facebook profile

```
const navigateToFacebookApp = async () => {
   await Linking.openURL(fbLink);
}

<Button onPress={navigateToFacebookApp}>Connect</Button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to deep link to a specific page or location in the Facebook mobile app on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149143/is-it-possible-to-deep-link-to-a-specific-page-or-location-in-the-facebook-mobil)

Comment: @UgurEren I need to use the deep link of fb in my react native app, so when user press on ``button`` connect they will be navigated to facebook app.